# Is there a succinct list anywhere of all the general genres of anime?

Tags: anime-production

If not can we make one here? It'd help a lot of people who ask "What anime should I watch if I like this?"

Comment: going by your last sentence this might be related: [Are there any anime suggestion engines?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/7337/1587). i would assume they also have lists of genres

Comment: True but it's not a break down by genre.

Comment: you mean something like this http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/tags?sort=num_likes&order=desc ?

Comment: @Darjeeling precisely! I could copy paste all of those into a nice list but it feels kind of wrong for me to take credit for it when I'm not the one who found it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anime-Planet have this really [nice list](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/tags?sort=num_likes&order=desc). The list contain all genre on their database. They have it on alphabetic order or number of likes order. If you want to find popular genre you can sort it by likes count. If you click on the genre you will find all anime with that genre. You can sort it by name or rating.

Answer (score 1):

I usually go [here](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/search/genre) to find new anime to watch, the genres are not sort able but it has a lot of themes to select other than just genre and it helps a lot when you want to find something you like, it also has a button in every anime page to search based on that anime's information.
https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/search/genre