# Anime / manga genre structure from Wikipedia

Tags: anime-production

I wonder is there an "official" list of anime / manga genres used in wikipedia that shows full genre structure with sub-categories. For example, in wikipedia you can find manga/anime articles with genre "mecha" that is a sub-category of "Science fiction" (for example, [Code Geass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Geass)) - described in animanga wiki page ([parameter - genre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_animanga#Header)).

There are forums (such as [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/40800/is-there-a-succinct-list-anywhere-of-all-the-general-genres-of-anime)) where people are suggesting anime websites, like [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/tags?sort=num_likes&order=desc) and [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime.php) but in these sites you have general list of all genres without dividing them into sub-categories.

**Edit based on first comment:** "general genre page" - yes, i found that page and it was the best article that describes genres in general, but it's missing some genres that are used in anime/manga wikipedia articles (like, mecha, slice of life, harem, ...). And about "a series of categories that wikipedia uses" (found this page before) - firstly, categories does not divide or group into sub-categories, secondly, there is links to categories that are not divided by the definition of genre from info-boxes (many of them are, but in these category lists anime/manga are "maybe" added by article creators, not automatically by wikipedia system based on info-box genre value + there are many questionable manga/anime that are added into these "categories" - you can correct me on that if necessary).

Comment: did you try looking at the infobox on the [anime page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anime) which not only has an expandable section on genre which links to a [general genre page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_genres) (not limited to just anime/manga) but also [a series of categories that wikipedia uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Anime_and_manga_by_genre) (not as exhaustive as the previous one)

Comment: Based on [Wikipedia's Manual of Style for Anime-and-Manga related articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Anime-_and_manga-related_articles#Categorization), the categorization should be based on the existing genre list, and only the most specific one (For *Code Geass*, since it's under "SciFi - Mecha", it's only listed as "Mecha"). Other than that, we are probably not the best people to know about how Wikipedia structured their A&M genre. You might consider asking on their [talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:WikiProject_Anime_and_manga) instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia is a community-built site, so the closest thing you can get to "official" are the [policy pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Policies_and_guidelines), which are adopted based on community consensus. But even then, enforcement can be inconsistent and spotty, especially with the more obscure articles (which is why editors often dismiss the ["Other stuff exists"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Other_stuff_exists) argument as invalid).

So on a Wikipedia article, there are two main places where the anime/manga's genre can be specified:

**1. The animanga infobox (at the top).**

The [Infobox animanga template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_animanga#Header) has these guidelines for the genre field:

> List more specific genres over general genres (ex. Mecha is a subgenre of Science fiction, therefore only Mecha should be listed instead of both). Genres should be based on what reliable sources list them and not on personal interpretations. If a genre cannot be cited to a reliable source, then it should not be listed.

The genres in the infobox depends a lot on what [reliable sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reliable_sources) characterize the anime/manga to be. Even if it seems very obvious to the common reader that the anime/manga is an instance of a specific genre, including it in the infobox is no good unless you can find a reliable source supporting it. (You may find some Wikipedia articles that have genres in the infobox that are unsourced, but shhhh, that's just the inconsistent enforcement thing from earlier.)

As a result, there isn't really a well-structured organizational hierarchy for the genres in the infobox. It's more like a mish-mash of what is considered to be a genre from various sources.

**2. The article's categories (at the bottom).**

Per Wikipedia 's [Manual of Style for anime/manga-related articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Anime-_and_manga-related_articles#Categorization), anime/manga articles are generally put into one or more subcategories of the three parent categories:

- [Category:Anime and manga by demographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Anime_and_manga_by_demographic)
- [Category:Anime and manga by genre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Anime_and_manga_by_genre)
- [Category:Anime and manga by topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Anime_and_manga_by_topic)

Editors are generally more lax with respect to verification requirements for categories (a category generally sticks around as long as it's at least somewhat apparent from the article content), but categories do get removed or challenged (e.g. using [Template:Uncited category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Uncited_category)).

Again, Wikipedia is a community-built site, so there isn't necessarily a consistent scheme or structure to the genre hierarchy. The structure of the genre categories most likely took shape over numerous small changes by various passerby contributors. Additions or changes to categories are usually implemented [boldly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Be_bold). Though larger or possibly controversial changes are typically posted at [Wikipedia:Categories for discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Categories_for_discussion) first to solicit feedback or approval.

This noticeboard isn't as popular as the Articles for Deletion noticeboard by a longshot, but things typically get one or two responses here. As an example of the kind of discussions that can take place here, here's a fairly straightforward [bulk category renaming proposal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Categories_for_discussion/Log/2018_June_16#Topic_based_anime_and_manga_categories) from 2018, which someone proposed so that the subcategories could have a more consistent naming scheme.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You gave me really good information to rely on with future research. I guess one of the solutions would be to suggest as wikipedia signed user to construct some kind of "recomended genre structure for animanga portal" or something like that.